# Failed to execute goal (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on project Unable to load compiled class

Tags: osgi, maven-3, aem, apache-felix, felix-dependency-manager

Have any one faced below error. why it causes.? am using the below version of plugins.

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
    </plugin>

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.20.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Private service properties for all services. -->
                            <properties>
                                <service.vendor>Adobe</service.vendor>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.11</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr
>   (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on project osgiexample.core:
>   E:\MY-Work\TESTProj\osgiexample\core\src\main\java\osgiexample\core\servlets\MyDataProviderServlet.java
>   : Unable to load compiled class:
>   osgiexample.core.servlets.MyDataProviderServlet -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1):

This means that the SCR plugin is unable to find a compiled class file corresponding to the file `MyDataProviderServlet.java`

I've only seen this happen in the following situations:

1. I had special characters in the path to my project, which caused the SCR plugin to fail to find the compiled classes.
2. I had a `*.java` file but its contents were temporarily commented out. The SCR plugin expected to find a compiled `*.class` file but there was nothing to compile (just comments). This caused an error message exactly like the one you saw.

Off the top of my head, I can't think of other cases where a class file would not be found by the SCR plugin without the Compiler plugin failing first.

I'd look for something unusual in the Java class itself. Does this happen for other classes with SCR annotations or just this one?

As a next step, I'd look at the file system. Could be a strange character or a file link confusing the plugin.

Finally, I'd inspect the rest of the Maven build. Perhaps you're using other plugins that might remove or otherwise mangle the class file prior to the SCR Plugin's execution?

Comment: thanks for the great explanation. finally am able to solve the issue by updating the maven version to latest maven 3.3.9 and commenting the `@service` and `@component` in my servlet where i was using them along with `@Servlet`. The uncompiled version of code can be found at [Uncompiled code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5YKUUmw4jJaSEtkUk1ZWVF2anc/view?usp=sharing) where in my custom servlet the above changes filed. Up vote for the good explanation.

Comment: @Var strange, in case of having all those annotations on a single class, I'd expect the SCR plugin to complain specifically about superfluous component definitions.

Comment: yup later i have removed all annotation except `@Servlet` which works fine. but strange observation is with only removing the `@Component` and having `@Service, @Servlet` works fine. but this leads me a question why `@Servlet and @Component` together is not able to compile.?

Comment: @VAr I take it you mean `@SlingServlet`. The semantics of the `@SlingServlet` annotation are that it implicitly defines the same descriptor as a combination of `@Service(Servlet.class)` and `@Component` with properties describing the path/selectors/methods/etc. In the eyes of the SCR plugin, a `@SlingServlet` annotation is a complete component definition. Having a separate `@Component` annotation leads to ambiguity and causes the plugin to throw an error.

Comment: yes sorry. i mean its `@SlingServlet`. yes it might be the cause of error. as below. **[ERROR] E:\MY-Work\testporj\osgiexample\core\src\main\java\osgiexample\core\servlets\MyDataProviderServlet.java [1:1]: Class has more than one component definition. Check the annotations and merge the definitions to a single definition.**

Comment: In my case changing my Java version solved the problem. I was using Java 18 for a project that need ver 8.

Comment: java version downgrade might solve this 
https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-tools/issues/226